# Split Entity into different partitions

Tags: clojure, schema, datomic

I am developing a webapp which makes use of datomic. Like every webapp I do have a user management which I want to provide as a separate module/library.

Now my Idea is to have a basic user schema with an email, password and an enabled flag. Then, every library that uses my user library would add additional domain specific user attributes.

So I would have two schemas like this:

```
 {:db/id #db/id [:db.part/db],
          :db/ident :friendui
          :db.install/_partition :db.part/db
          :db/doc "The partition of the database for releases"}
  {:db/id #db/id [:db.part/db]
          :db/ident :friendui/id
          :db/valueType :db.type/uuid
          :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
          :db/unique :db.unique/identity
          :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db
          :db/doc "A unique identifier for any element"}
  ;; users
  {:db/id #db/id [:db.part/db]
          :db/ident :user/email
          :db/index true
          :db/unique :db.unique/identity
          :db/valueType :db.type/string
          :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
          :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
]...
```

And the lib that uses the user library like this:

```
  {:db/id #db/id [:db.part/db],
          :db/ident :lweb
          :db.install/_partition :db.part/db
          :db/doc "The partition of the database for releases"}
  {:db/id #db/id [:db.part/db]
          :db/ident :lweb/id
          :db/valueType :db.type/uuid
          :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
          :db/unique :db.unique/identity
          :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db
          :db/doc "A unique identifier for any element"}


  ;; users
  {:db/id #db/id [:db.part/db]
          :db/ident :user/attr1
          :db/index false
          :db/valueType :db.type/string
          :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
          :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
```

....

Now the problem that I see is that I have two different partitions which should be merged into on.
Is there a way to solve that with datomic?

**Update** The more I think about it, the more I guess that i just have to define the schema within the using library and declare what the user library needs in the schema.

Comment: No experience with datomic but doesn't vanilla merge, assoc, dissoc work with these hash-maps?

Comment: Yea, they can be worked on with merge, assoc, ... but I wonder if there is an easier, more idiomatic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design wise, I think the proper approach is for your library to be schema-agnostic.

If what you're building is a library, schema shouldn't be defined in there.

Alternatives for me are:

- Your library delegates db actions using multimethods implemented in your application.
- Your library receives database and field mapping on some initialization function.

The second approach just maps schema fields to known library keywords such as :email and :friendui.

First approach is even datomic agnostic.

Comment: Hm, I guess alternative one makes no sense for me as my lib should exactly do that, CRUD on users with datomic (maybe db-independent some day). Alternative two sounds good and I think thats the only option here. Or, another idea is to assume at least some fields have to be provided and the rest can be given via a & more parameter.

Comment: You may assume defaults for your required fields if no mapping is specified but IMO you shouldn't force your library users to use your exact field ids.

Comment: You are right, so I will go with the approach that the client library has to provide a config file with the database-uri and a field mapping. Thank you very much.